# Store multiple versions in hbase row with the same family: qualifier but different timestamps.

Tags: java, hbase

I want to store multiple versions of a row which has the same family: qualifier but different value and timestamps.

```
    Put put = new Put(Bytes.toBytes(key));
    put.add(family, qualifier,timestamp0, value0);
    put.add(family, qualifier,timestamp1, value1);
    table.put(put);
```

However, only one of them which had the higher timestamp will be stored in the table. The issue is not because of MaxVersions. Is there any way I could have hbase to store both versions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote a test, and it is ok.
pls check your config.

```
    byte[] rowKey = Bytes.toBytes("allen_test_row");
    Put put = new Put(rowKey);
    put.add(ColumnFamilyName, QName1, 1000, Bytes.toBytes("a"));
    put.add(ColumnFamilyName, QName1, 2000, Bytes.toBytes("b"));
    table.put(put);

    Get get = new Get(rowKey);
    get.setMaxVersions(10);
    Result result = table.get(get);
    KeyValue[] keyValues = result.raw();
    Assert.assertEquals(2, keyValues.length);
    //have a and b both.
    Assert.assertEquals('a' + 'b', keyValues[0].getValue()[0]
            + keyValues[1].getValue()[0]);
```

when you get the data from hbase?
did you specify the maxversion?

BTW
you can use https://github.com/zhang-xzhi/simplehbase to one rowkey - many DO mapping.

Answer (score 0):

No.  You can only have one value in a column for a given rowkey.  If you want another value, you'll have to give it its own rowkey, or put it in a different column.

Comment: If the qualifier was different that wouldn't be a problem. Sure we can have multiple values in a row. (versioned data)

Answer (score 0):

You're in wrong.

Hbase by default has 3 versions in a cell.It means that if you save and update 3 times in a cell  hbase stores them with time stamps in 3 versions. 
You cannot store in a cell with time stamp.

If you want another value, you'll have to put it in a different column family or different column.

Comment: I am puting data into HBase table through shell command line. But when I scan it I get only latest value .. scan 'emp',{STARTROW =>'2',STOPROW=>'2',VERSIONS=>12} .....is there different way to get versions ? Or is versioning not "switched on" in my DB ?