# Is it possible to have a row in HBase with same rowkey, same column family, same column qualifier but different values?

Tags: hbase

Are the following commands possible?

```
put 't1', 'r1', 'c1:q1', 'v1'
put 't1', 'r1', 'c1:q1', 'v2'
```

So, if I query 'r1' and 'c1:q1', I would like to get back both 'v1' and 'v2'. From my experiments so far, it seems it overwrites the value, instead of adding another value.

I have searched this and other sites but I haven't yet found a similar question. The closest I came to was [Store multiple versions in hbase row with the same family: qualifier but different timestamps.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22587037/store-multiple-versions-in-hbase-row-with-the-same-family-qualifier-but-differe) but that is about adding through Java while mine is through shell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can alter the property of hbase table and can enable version.Here is a simple example.

alter ‘Employee′, NAME => ‘EmployeeInfo′, VERSIONS => 5

Here Employee is table name and EmployeeInfo is column family.